How can I write code that references its own class many to many while coding an ASP.NET Core database?
I have a "Word" class and I am trying to create a table that references "word" to keep the synonyms and antonyms of the words in this class in the database.
My word class
[Table("Word", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Word
{
    public int Word_ID { get; set; }
    public string Word_EN { get; set; }
    public NounVerbAdj WordType { get; set; }
    public string? Sentence_En { get; set; }  
    public string? Sentence_Tr { get; set; } 
    public bool Verify { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Antonym> Antonym1  { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Antonym> Antonym2  { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Synonym> Synonym1 { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Synonym> Synonym2 { get; set; }
}

public class WordConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Word>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Word> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Word_ID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.Word_EN).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(30);
        builder.Property(x => x.WordType).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(1);
        builder.Property(x => x.Verify).IsRequired(true).HasDefaultValue(false);

        builder.Property(x => x.Sentence_En).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(200);
        builder.Property(x => x.Sentence_Tr).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(200);
        
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.Word_ID).IsUnique(true);

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Word_ID);

    }
}

And my antonym class:
[Table("Antonym", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Antonym
{
    public int Word_ID_1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word_1 { get; set; }

    public int Word_ID_2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word_2 { get; set; }
}

public class AntonymConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Antonym>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Antonym> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(wk => new { wk.Word_ID_1, wk.Word_ID_2 });

        builder.HasOne(wk => wk.Word_1) 
            .WithMany(w => w.Antonym1)
            .HasForeignKey(wk => wk.Word_ID_1);

        builder.HasOne(wk => wk.Word_2)
            .WithMany(w => w.Antonym2)
            .HasForeignKey(wk => wk.Word_ID_2);
    }
}

Errors:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Antonym_Word_Word_ID_2' on table 'Antonym' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I just want to crate these tables and relationships:

Each word data can be referenced by multiple synonyms and antonyms.I want to create this relationship between words by keeping the month languages of the words in a different table.
How can I prevent cycles or other problems? I can not run EF migration to update database.

ASP.NET is the web framework - it has per se nothing to do with data storage etc. - therefore an "ASP.NET database" is not something that truly exists ...... Entity Framework is the data access framework - so you could say "a database generated and managed by Entity Framework" - but in the end, a database really resides in a database server - whether that be SQL Server, Oracle, IBM DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL or something else entirely .....

I would recommend maintaining Atonyms and Synonyms as related tables with a foreign key constraint defining the Word they relate to. Your current implementation is arguably limited and cumbersome to extend as/when you want to add more atonyms or synonyms it would require extra columns.

There are incredibly many questions on this exception. Please try to find them. The answer is easy. Keep in mind that the exception is from the database, not primarily EF, and it already tells you what to do.
